# mysql in python with visual studio code

Tags: python, mysql

I installed python 2.7.15 version on my computer (windows 10 64 bit) and installed mysql using `pip install mysql-connector` and from command prompt i can see mysql-connector working fine and i can even query data but when i tried in visual studio code i keep getting error "pylint unable to find mysql.connector". can you guys tell me what i am doing wrong.

I tried searching google and did not find any specific answers to it and i am struggling for sometime to fix it.

Here is the sample code

```
import mechanicalsoup # Don’t forget to import the new module
from selenium import webdriver  
import re
from datetime import datetime
import urllib
import mysql.connector


URL = "https://www.samplewebsite.com/Security/Login"
LOGIN = "username"
PASSWORD = "password"
shipdate = ""

# Create a browser object
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(URL)

browser.find_element_by_id('Username').send_keys(LOGIN)
browser.find_element_by_id('Password').send_keys(PASSWORD)
browser.find_element_by_id('Login').click()
```

Comment: can anyone answer this please

Comment: Maybe noone answers because noone installs Python 2 today (where the end of life is less than half a year away).